# Do I need to use "an" in this sentence?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I need to write a sentence, and I have problems with whether I need to use "an" or not.

I use the text of books to search for similar sentences, since i'm a beginner and I have problems with grammar.

The sentence, which I need to write:
Surgeons can plan (an) operation.

The problem is that I don't know if I should necessarily use "an"? I have found in books both a variant with "an" and without. And that makes it difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Yes, if you are referring to a single operation you need an article.

Comment: @KateBunting the problem is that there is no definition of the number of operations in the task context. OR do you mean that if the sentence does not contain plural gender, then I should use "an"?

Comment: If you are talking about operations in general: _Surgeons plan operations_. If it's a particular one; _Surgeons plan an operation_ or _the operation_.

Comment: @KateBunting Perhaps I understand you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Surgeons can plan (an) operation.'

In this sentence, you definitely need the 'an'. It's a particular operation and only one of them, and you are emphasizing the sort of person who can do the planning.

If you have a particular surgeon or surgeon team in mind, you might write 'My (or our) surgeon(s) can plan the operation.' And if it's a particular operation you have in mind, by a particular surgeon, 'My surgeon can plan the operation.' The sense of the last two differs very little.

If you had meant the general idea of capacity for planning, emphasis on the ability of a certain class of person to do a certain sort of action (no number of persons, or actions, implied), then 'Surgeons can plan operations.'

Comment: But what if it is necessary to emphasize the possibility (can plan), but you need to write about the singular (operation)?

Comment: Interesting. Depends on other things I guess. If I understand your question, then 'The (or My or Our) Surgeon(s) can plan an operation" (when you are not emphasizing the precise operation in mind) and 'The (or My or Our) Surgeon(s) can plan the operation' when you have a specific operation in mind.

Comment: Yishmeray, thanks you!